# Do I need to buy Mists of Pandaria to participate in pet battles?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm really looking forward to the pet battle system that's supposed to be coming with *Mists of Pandaria*, but I'm not clear on how it's going to be unlocked.

Do you need to have the expansion keyed to your account to access pet battles, or will it just be available for anyone around the time *Mists of Pandaria* is released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pet battles will be locked until the day *Mists of Pandaria* is released (so, September 25th, 2012), but [will not require the purchase of the expansion](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6080181259#9):

> The feature will go live with the box release date of MoP. It will be available to all players, MoP is not required.